# Cisco SG200-50, accessing a network printer from 2 VLANs

Tags: cisco, vlan, network-printer

The requirement is to create an additional (guest) VLAN (a [Cisco SG200-series smart switch](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/sg200-50-50-port-gigabit-smart-switch/model.html) is used) so that the devices on the guest VLAN could not see those on the internal network (the default VLAN), however they should still be able to print on the network printer (a [Samsung CLX-3180-series printer](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/printers/CLX-3185FW/XAA-specs))

Is this possible without any additional hardware and if yes, how would the setup look like? Would assigning a port (the one the printer is connected to) to 2 VLANs simultaneously be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SG200-50 is a layer 2 switch only. So while it supports grouping of ports to VLANs it cannot route traffic between them without an external router or L3 switch. You will not be able to assign the printer to two VLAN simultaneously.